# LilyPond: Is it possible to revert to "atonal" key?

Tags: lilypond

In LilyPond, there is a distinction between specifying `\key c \major` and leaving the key blank. In the former case, transposing instruments will change the key signature accordingly, while in the latter case, no key signature will be added. Using `\transpose c d`, for instance, will add two sharps if `\key c \major` is listed, but not when no key is listed.

What happens when I go from an ‘open key’ section to a tonal section, and back to ‘open key’? I've tried `\revert \key`, but this seems to be bad syntax. Is there a way to revert to a key-free area?

Minimal example, which should have a key signature of one flat in the second section but no sharps or flats elsewhere:

```
\transpose c d {
  % Open key
  c8 e f g e d des c

  \key c \minor
  c es g es f d c b

  % How to return to open key??
  c8 e f g e d des c
}
```

Comment: Hi John, can I suggest you to subscribe to the *lilypond-user mailing list* and also post your question there? Usually you get your answer in less than 24h, since some very knowledgeable people are participating in the mailing list. This is the page for subcribing: [link](https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/lilypond-user) Please do not get me wrong, I am always happy to see *LilyPond* questions here at *StackOverflow* and I encourage you to keep posting here; I just wanted to direct you to a faster way of solving your problem. Take care.

Comment: If you find the answer, could you post back it here to StackOverflow?

Comment: @sonicwizard I'll do so! The workaround that works for my purposes is just to use tags, but that really bothers me. I hope there is an answer.

Comment: @sonicwizard It is a great idea to post a solution back at *StackOverflow*. To be very honest, when I post my questions concerning *LilyPond* here, most of the time I do not expect to receive an answer, but if I do find one I surely explain it here! If a lot of users do the same, hopefully soon there will be a bigger community of *LilyPond* users frequenting this website.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the LilyPond mailing list, I was told that there really isn't a way for this to be done—although the following is a workaround as regards the problem with transposition:

```
\withMusicProperty #'untransposable ##t \key c \major
```

This code prevents C major from being transposed.

---

Another workaround, which I have used, is to use tags, so that transposing scores use different keys than C scores. Here is an overview of tags: http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.12/Documentation/user/lilypond/Different-editions-from-one-source